# How to generate JavaScript from a template with terminal similar to Laravel's Artisan?

Tags: javascript, php, terminal, generator, laravel-artisan

I have been recently been working with Laravel, and [Artisan has several useful `make` commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#generating-commands) that generates php from template stubs on the fly based off a class name, as well as allowing for custom `make` commands to speed things up.

Short of copy-pasting, there an easy tool that lets me generate plain JS in a similar way based on a templates that allows me to specify some variables to be replaced, then generated in my project?

*The ultimate goal of mine for this project is to run a single terminal command with some arguments that generate all the files I need (at least 8-10 PHP files, as well as around 4 JS files), all put into the right directories that lets me do minimal "plugging in" so I can start using them right away. I can chain custom artisan commands, but the next step is getting some kind of terminal JS generator. The nature of the project is that there is approx. 12-14 files that need to be generated and generically filled in before being able to interface with a database table and the front end, so you can understand why I want to do this.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with bash like this

```
#!/bin/bash
file_location=path/to/dir/$1.js
if [ -e $1 ]; then
  echo "File $1.js already exists!"
else
  cat > $file_location <<EOF
let hi = '$2'
console.log(hi)
EOF
fi
```

$1 is the filename and $2 is another parameter you can pass to the script to be written in the js file.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [hygen](https://github.com/jondot/hygen). I don't know what your output files are supposed to look like, but hygen allows you to create your own templates and generators. [This has a relevant code snippet](https://github.com/jondot/hygen#case-changing) that displays some JS code. I can't give any advice beyond that as I've not used it thus far.

If this is looking like a bit too much, you can always use VS Code's templates to build up a base, but you won't have any params. A VS Code extension could overcome that I'd guess, but then you're not within a cli.